# Convert Doctrine entity into a mock for unit test

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, doctrine-orm, mocking, entitymanager

I'm trying to create a mock of the entity manager for unit tests that returns a deep entity structure.

Basicaly I want to transform this :

```
  $p1 = new Product();
  $p1->setName("product 1");
  // ...

  $c = new Command();
  $c->setDate(new Date());
  $c->setId(1);
  $c->addProduct($p1);
  // ...
```

Into this :

```
  p1 = $this->getMock('\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Product');
  $p1->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getName')
        ->will($this->returnValue("product 1"));
  // ...

  $c = $this->getMock('\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Command');
  $c->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getDate')
        ->will($this->returnValue(new Date()));
  $c->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getId')
        ->will($this->returnValue(1));
  $c->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getProducts')
        ->will($this->returnValue(array($p1)));
  // ...
```

Is there a simple and not so verbose way to get this ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use mockery is a bit simpler

Comment: Maybe you should look at [BazingaFakerBundle](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaFakerBundle), a Symfony2 bundle based on [Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker).

Answer (score 1):

Thake a look at Phake: http://phake.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

You can Method Stubbing like:

```
    $this->item1 = Phake::mock('Item');
    $this->item2 = Phake::mock('Item');
    $this->item3 = Phake::mock('Item');

    Phake::when($this->item1)->getPrice()->thenReturn(100);
    Phake::when($this->item2)->getPrice()->thenReturn(200);
    Phake::when($this->item3)->getPrice()->thenReturn(300);

    $this->shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();
    $this->shoppingCart->addItem($this->item1);
    $this->shoppingCart->addItem($this->item2);
    $this->shoppingCart->addItem($this->item3);
```